# Meteor+Angular2 , image file upload

Tags: meteor, angular, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, angular-meteor

I have copied the zip file from tutorial as is, after creating the upload images feature, and it doesnt show the small pictures near the file when uploaded, and also after uploading the first file, no matter what you upload after that it always showing and saving the only first file you uploaded.
by the way is there any example of meteor-angular2 + upload files to google storage/ s3 project?

Comment: This might help point you in the right direction.  Simple vanilla js code i wrote you can put in your angular code. https://github.com/NicholasEli/Meteor-Image-Upload

Comment: thanks but I'm looking for angular2 version and not blaze

Comment: @NicholasByDesign is trying to say that his code is basically simple JS, and would work for you. Although doing a Meteor call to pass image data to the server is very inefficient, as the upload will be significantly larger than the original image

Comment: Another option would be to use cloudinary package. It's pretty simple and keeps you from reinventing the wheel. https://github.com/Lepozepo/cloudinary

Comment: If you look on http://atmospherejs.com you will see that there are several Angular directives that people have done. These would be relatively easy to upgrade to Angular2, or if you are not confident doing that you could ask one of the authors to do it and re-publish. Also worth looking at is https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload - Danial is very active in supporting that, and may also provide an ng2 version at some stage :)